# What is Backed Collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections

These methods return Backed Collection since change in one Collection affects the other Collection.[ kind of write through process ]

> ```
> headSet(e, b)     Returns a subset ending at element e and exclusive of e
>
> headMap(k, b)     Returns a submap ending at key k and exclusive of key k
>
> tailSet(e, b)     Returns a subset starting at and inclusive of element e
>
> tailMap(k, b)     Returns a submap starting at and inclusive of key k
>
> subSet(s, b, e, b)    Returns a subset starting at element s and ending just before element e
>
> subMap(s, b, e, b)    Returns a submap starting at key s and ending just before key e
> ```

Then what's the difference with `Arrays.asList()` method? The method copies an array into a List.The API says "changes to the returned list 'write through' to the array & vice versa".

So, is it too a Backed Collection? If it's, then there's toArray() method in List interface --is that a Backed Collection too?

Is there any other method like `Arrays.asList()` which allows write through? How can I find out if the method allows write through or not just by seeing the method signature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `Arrays.asList` returns a list backed by the array, because it doesn't make a copy, but `Collection.toArray` makes a copy, so it is not backed by the collection.

You cannot tell if a method returns a collection backed by its inputs just from the signature -- only from the documentation.  Usually, it's documented using the words "backed by," "view," or the like.  There are many examples -- `List.subList`, for example, `Collections.newSetFromMap`, and many more -- as well as countless examples in third-party libraries.

Comment: +1 You may want to mention the often used `keySet`/`values` of maps, and `headMap`/`subMap`/`tailMap` views of the tree map.

Comment: Well, to be fair, `headMap`, `subMap`, and `tailMap` were already mentioned by the OP.

Comment: You're right, he did! I didn't read the list of examples from the question, so I missed these three.